# How to design a html form to feed something like hirachical

Tags: html, design-patterns, webforms

in html

Every node have it's subnode [not required] can be have parent node.

i want to design a webform which can be used to feed something and after submission i update them using json.

after that i need that

without going anywhere he can feed his childnode and parent node.

how i can make a webform who can solve this issue for me

Comment: Can you get more vague? Can you please explain what you are trying to accomplish, without talking about nodes please?

Answer (score 0):

For node, you can use html unit list :

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

To make it dynamic, try you own from:
http://woork.blogspot.com/2007/10/ajax-add-new-element-into-list-using.html